# Django get_or_create how to use it on foriegnkey?

Tags: python, django

How do i use get_or_create in foriegnkey? i have this code, that if the `Student_Users`(foriegnkey) doesnt exist the data will inserted and if not the data will update, but in my case even though the `Student_Users` exist the record inserted.

```
insert_data, created = studentsRecord.objects.get_or_create(
  Student_Users=student,
  School_Year = schoolyear
  Education_Levels = educationlevel
)
if not created:
  insert_data.Student_Users = student
  insert_data.School_Year = schoolyear
  insert_data.Education_Levels = educationlevel
  insert_data.save()
```

Comment: A few things. Have you tried `update_or_create`? Do you have a unique constraint across those fields? Is `Education_Levels` a reverse foreign key or a many to many field?

Comment: i didnt tried `update_or_create` , the `Education_Levels` is a many to many field

Comment: I just want that if the `Student_Users` id is existed in `studentsRecord model` the `Education_Levels` field will update only

Comment: You can't use these methods with a ManyToManyField like you want. You'll need to redesign your models so that you have a `through` model in that relationship. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: okay, thanks. ikeep it mind